# bind to widget service from a non-activity class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, service, binding

My android app has a widget.

This is the widget service `OnCreate`:

```
public class AppWidgetService extends Service {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

private static AppWidgetService mInstance = null;

..
}
```

Basically this service scans a file that is filled from within the app.

Whenever the app changes this file content I want to call the service's `re-scan` (aka refresh) method.

I have thought to create a new class (non-Activity) `widgetServiceBinder`

which will expose static public bounded service member.

.

I have a few problems:

1) when the app works, I don't know if the widget is active in the user's home page.

Thus I don't know if the service is running.

If it's not running I don't want to create it, as it has no need as long as the user

didn't add it to his home screen.

Can it be that the widget exists but when I bind to it I call a service that wasn't created

via calling `OnCreate` ?

2) I ask because I have tried binding from an activity like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample). I manage to debug in the service

methods, but it seems all of its member are null. I cannot init `mInstance` as its static.

3) I have tried binding from an Activity just for simplicity. I actually want to create a

new class (non-Activity) `widgetServiceBinder`. How can I bind from there to the service?

I cannot call `getApplicationContext` from that manager.

4) I have sent the Application's context to the service method from the outside,

but then I have to penetrate this to all methods that uses `mInstance` otherwise I get a

nullPointer exception.

How would you suggest solving this?

Comment: @user1236327 I revised the question you have answered before

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can only help you with binding in non-activity.

There are few ways to do it,

1: creating a constructor which you pass in context (activity).

2: creating singeltone which can use by static way.

The best way will be passing context in constructor .